# Changing width of a column from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridviewcolumn

I with this code marking the first column from `DataGridView`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

but because the low width, the numbers are not shown properly, how can I change the width the first column ?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set an appropriate [`DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159167(v=vs.110).aspx) value to `RowHeadersWidthSizeMode`.

For example:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to handle the OnRowDataBound event of your gridview.

```
protected void dataGridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[YourColumnIndex].With = YourValue;
            }
        }
```